# Qual o jeito correto de carregar dados do AsyncStorage ao carregar o Aplicativo?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Estou tendo problemas ao carregar dados do AsyncStorage, pois ele está sendo sempre carregado por ultimo, independente da ordem de execução.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';

import {IPSERVIDOR} from '../const';
import {mostrarErro, sucesso} from '../common';

const Config = () => {
  function GravarIp(value) {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(IPSERVIDOR, 'http://' + value);
    } catch (e) {
      mostrarErro('Ocorreu um erro ao gravar o IP: ' + e);
    }
  }

async function UseCarregarConfig() {
const [getServer, setServidor] = useState('');

try {
  const Ip = await AsyncStorage.getItem(IPSERVIDOR);

  if (Ip !== null) {
    axios
      .get(`${Ip}/usuarios/getUsuarios`)
      .then(_ => {
        setServidor(Ip);
        console.log('CarregarConfig then:' + Ip);
      })
      .catch(_ => {
        console.log('CarregarConfig catch:' + Ip);
        setServidor(null);
      });
  } else {
    setServidor(null);
  }
} catch (e) {
  mostrarErro('Ocorreu um erro ao retornar o IP: ' + e);
}

return getServer;
}

  return {GravarIp, UseCarregarConfig};
};

export default Config;
```

Ao instanciar a classe  no Navigator principal ou tela inicial e usar o UseCarregarConfig(), independente se está no constructor ou componentDidMount, ele sempre retorna o resultado por ultimo, sendo assim, não consigo capturar o IP do servidor na hora certa para requisitar o backend.

Pelo que entendi ele executa o callback e com isso o método só é executado no fim da instrução de carga, mesmo adicionando o await

Answer (score -1):

Fala mano, beleza? Vi ali que vc importou um useEffect porém não usou.
Segue uma idéia:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';

import {IPSERVIDOR} from '../const';
import {mostrarErro, sucesso} from '../common';

const Config = () => {
  function GravarIp(value) {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(IPSERVIDOR, 'http://' + value);
    } catch (e) {
      mostrarErro('Ocorreu um erro ao gravar o IP: ' + e);
    }
  }

async function UseCarregarConfig() {
const [getServer, setServidor] = useState('');
const [ipAddress, setIpAddress] = useState('');

const getIp = useCallback(async() => {
   const storagedIP = await AsyncStorage.getItem(IPSERVIDOR)
   setIpAddress(storagedIP)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   getIp()
}, [getIP])

try {
   const Ip = await AsyncStorage.getItem(IPSERVIDOR);

if (ipAddress !== null) {
   axios
   .get(`${ipAddress}/usuarios/getUsuarios`)
   .then(_ => {
     setServidor(ipAddress);
     console.log('CarregarConfig then:' + ipAddress);
   })
   .catch(_ => {
    console.log('CarregarConfig catch:' + ipAddress);
    setServidor(null);
  });
  } else {
    setServidor(null);
  }
} catch (e) {
  mostrarErro('Ocorreu um erro ao retornar o IP: ' + e);
}
 return getServer;
}
 return {GravarIp, UseCarregarConfig};
};

export default Config;
```

Fiz mais ou menos de cabeça. testa ai e vê se te dá uma luz

Comment: Bom dia!
Estava pensando que o problema na execução era as instruções, porém o que acontece é que quando chamo uma função async, independente di método de ciclo de vida que estiver, sempre é executado por ultimo, ele não aguarda a callback ser resolvida